# How should I test whether batch script variable is empty or not?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I created the following batch script, called `test.bat`:

```
@echo off

if not "%test%"=="" (
    echo 555
    echo %test%
)
```

Then I run:

```
set test=test (1).exe
".\test.bat"
```

Then I get an error: `.exe was unexpected at this time`

If I modify my script to

```
@echo off

if not %test%=="" (
    echo 555
    echo %test%
)
```

I get an error:
`(1).exe=="" was unexpected at this time.`

My string to compare are going to be file names so I must support spaces, `.exe` and `(1)`.

Comment: Can you not change the structure to **1.** ```@Echo Off```, **2.** ```If "%test%" == "" GoTo :EOF```, **3.** ```Echo 555```, **4.** ```Echo %test%```. Then run ```Set "test=test (1).exe"```, and ```Call "test.bat"```. If not, what about, **1.** ```@Echo Off```, **2.** ```SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion```, **3.** ```If Not "%test%" == "" (```, **4.** ```Echo 555```, **5.** ```Echo !test!```, **6.** ```)```. Then run ```Set "test=test (1).exe"```, and ```Call "test.bat"```.

Answer (score 0):

Given your first code, if `test` is set to `test (1).exe` then `cmd` interprets it as

```
if not "test (1).exe"=="" (
    echo 555
    echo test (1).exe
)
```

so `"test (1).exe"`<>`""` and we execute the code. The `)` in the `echo` statement matches the `(` at the end of the `if` line and closes the block. Batch then complains that the `.exe` makes no sense.

If you wanted to `echo` the `)` then you'd need to escape it by preceding it with a caret `^)`

If you `rem`-out that `echo` line, the code acts as expected.

With the second code, `cmd` interprets it as

```
if not test (1).exe=="" (
    echo 555
    echo test (1).exe
)
```

so `if` is expecting a comparison-operator after `test` but it sees `(1).exe==""` which is not a comparison-operator and hence `cmd` reports it as an error.

Probably you should use

```
if defined test (dosomething) else (doanotherthing)
```

structured as

```
if not defined test goto noparam
echo 555
echo %test%
:noparam
```

Which avoids having to escape the `)`

Tip: Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.